# How to set a control as a property in other control in XAML in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I want to set a control as a property in XAML.

I have a custom Control **BlurredImage** that sends another control (XAML view or Visual Element) as the Root for generating blurred background for the current Image. I have implemented custom control.

**Here's my custom control:**

```cs
public class BlurredImage : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty RootProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Root), typeof(VisualElement), typeof(BlurredImage), propertyChanged: RootPropertyChanged);

    public VisualElement Root { get => (VisualElement)GetValue(RootProperty); set => SetValue(RootProperty, value); }

    static void RootPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (BlurredImage)bindable;

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var imageStream = await DependencyService.Get<IVisualElementExtension>().PlatformCaptureImageAsync(control. Root, Color.Red);
            control. Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream);
        });
    }
}
```

The `RootPropertyChanged()` is added here for reference, it works properly when capturing an image of a UI by a button click, it only has a problem, when I specify `Root="{Binding someView, Source={x:Reference this}}"`

**Here is my XAML code when I am creating BlurredImage in my XAML Page:**

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout">
    <BoxView Color="Blue" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" />
    <Label Text="This will be blurred" />
</StackLayout>

<ext:BlurredImage Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                  Source="waterfront.jpg" 
                  Root="{Binding Source={x:Reference stackLayout}}" />
```

I have provided `BlurredImage`'s Source just to avoid error, As I am getting an error, if the source is not specified.

What this code does is: capture a screenshot of the control that is given in the `Root` property, and then set the `Source` of the `BlurredImage`.

I just want to get the control named `stackLayout` and pass it under the `Root` property of the `BlurredImage`. When I specify Root as above, I am getting error as render is null in platform code `var render = Platform.GetRenderer(view);` This is probably because I am not able to set Root property value to the control in XAML.

Am I doing everything correctly? How can I pass a control as a property value from XAML?

Comment: Could you provide some more XAML Page code ?

Comment: You can see `Xamarin.Forms Relative Bindings`. And check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor)